# How to automatically launch bash shell when opening terminal or in console mode?

Tags: bash, users

I create a normal user account in ubuntu using "useradd" command, but the problem is that I have to type "bash" to launch the bash shell for this user account in both the console mode (in a tty, through ctrl+alt+Fn) and the remote mode (via ssh). The most important part of bash shell for me is the auto-completion function, so my question is that how I could make the bash shell launch automatically when logging into the account.

I use ubuntu 13.04 32bit version. I appreciate for any advice!

Comment: [How do you use a shell other than bash at a terminal as default?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/710/how-do-you-use-a-shell-other-than-bash-at-a-terminal-as-default)

Comment: I think the below proposed approaches can answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, check if `useradd` shows a default value for `SHELL`. To do that, issue:

```
useradd -D
```

This will output something like:

```
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/sh
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no
```

These values are taken from `/etc/default/useradd`. Now, you have 2 solutions:

1. Edit `/etc/default/useradd`, and change the value of `SHELL`, or
2. Override the shell's value when adding user with: `useradd -D -s /bin/bash`

For more information see `man useradd`.

Comment: All true and all useful, +1, but it won't help the OP. This will only affect the _next_ user created, not the one that already exists.

Comment: Another question, as now I create a user account without home directory, its home directory defaults to the root "/", so how could I still configure the bash profile for this account? I mean for the user account with home directory, its bash profile is in the local directory (bashrc, etc.), but I do not find such file when logging in with the account I created. Thanks!

Comment: Will it work, if I just copy the bashrc file to the root directory from other account?

Answer (score 20):

You probably need to set bash as your new users's login shell. If you are logged in as that user:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

To change it for another user

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

In future you might want to use `adduser` instead of the low-level `useradd`, since it defaults to setting bash as the new login shell.

You can check the login shell (among other details) by looking at the /etc/passwd file or using

```
getent passwd username
```

Comment: Good approach, +1 from me!

Comment: I think this is also very useful, thanks for answering!